# Error con certificado SSL en Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Ya he instalado Certificados SSL en web anteriores, pero me acaba de pasar un caso muy raro que nunca había visto en el que me menciona que estoy solicitando una imagen de una página en HTTP pero en ningún momento he hecho eso. No sé como solucionarlo.

Aquí les dejo lo que me envía:

> jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:3
>
> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.javisac.com.pe/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://maggiesadler.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/ajax-loader.gif'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Si tienen alguna idea espero su apoyo.

Comment: ¿`http://maggiesadler.com/` es tu dominio?, parece que tu wordpress hace caso omiso a utilizar https si lo tienes configurado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema viene de tu hoja de estilos (línea 431 de tu HTML):

```
@charset 'UTF-8';
/* Slider */
.slick-loading .slick-list
{
    background: #fff url('http://maggiesadler.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/ajax-loader.gif') center center no-repeat;
}
```

Estás cargando una imagen HTTP en una página HTTPS.

Si indicas explícitamente el [esquema](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esquema_de_URI) HTTP (`http:`) estás obligando a cargar contenido no seguro en una web segura, pero si omites el esquema usará el mismo esquema que la página que estás visitando (`https:`).

Un ejemplo de omisión de esquema:

```
@charset 'UTF-8';
/* Slider */
.slick-loading .slick-list
{
    background: #fff url('//maggiesadler.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/ajax-loader.gif') center center no-repeat;
}
```

El error aparentemente lo da jQuery, pero es una cadena de llamadas entre jQuery y Slick desencadenado por las siguientes líneas javascript:

```
$('.divicon-items').slick({
    pauseOnFocus:false,
    /* ... */
});
```

---

Por cierto, estás dejando enlaces a varios archivos locales en tu hoja de estilos:

```
/* Icons */
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

    src: url('file:///C:/Users/msadler/Desktop/slick-1.5.7/slick/fonts/slick.eot');
    src: url('file:///C:/Users/msadler/Desktop/slick-1.5.7/slick/fonts/slick.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('file:///C:/Users/msadler/Desktop/slick-1.5.7/slick/fonts/slick.woff') format('woff'),
      url('file:///C:/Users/msadler/Desktop/slick-1.5.7/slick/fonts/slick.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('file:///C:/Users/msadler/Desktop/slick-1.5.7/slick/fonts/slick.svg#slick') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, en este caso si era un código css que había puesto para dar un efecto de carrusel y en el ejemplo daban todo ese código y lo copie y pegue.

Answer (score 0):

El contenido mixto ocurre cuando algún recurso de tu web (normalmente imágenes) apuntan a un dominio http, mientras que tu página apunta a un dominio https.

Localiza donde tienes la url de esa imagen en wordpress y sustituye:

http://maggiesadler.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/ajax-loader.gif

por:

https://maggiesadler.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/ajax-loader.gif

Si utilizas algún tipo de plantilla en tu página, normalmente suele estar en la configuración del tema. Basta con eliminar ese campo y volverlo a cargar desde tu carpeta de Medios.